# Regex to include all intranet sites but exclude http(s)://localhost

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to come up with a JS regex that will include any intranet site (with the simple definition of any host name that does not include `.`), but will exclude `localhost`.

I've got the first part: `http(s)?\:\/\/[^\.\/]+(\/.*)*`
I am struggling with the second part. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead:

```
/^http(s)?\:\/\/(?!localhost[:\/])[^\.\/]+(\/.*)*$/
```

Comment: Yep, that's pretty close. Though, it seems to wrongly match non-port-80 locahost URLs (`http://localhost:8080/`). Here's the one that works for that case too: `http(s)?\:\/\/(?!localhost)[^\.\/]+(\/.*)*`. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. It will also wrongly match `http://francip@localhost/`. I decided I can live with these limitations for my purposes. :-)